# Groovy 2.3 traits on web console

Tags: groovy, traits

I wanted to try out the latest [`trait` feature of groovy 2.3](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT/html/documentation/core-traits.html), but was unable to execute them on default [Groovy web console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) as well as [Ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Are there any other Web consoles available for groovy 2.3? Or I will have to install 2.3 on local machine to try it out?

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
trait FlyingAbility{
    void fly(){println "I am flying"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.3 isn't out yet, you can download release candidates.

None of the web consoles use the RC version of groovy

So you'll have to download it and try it locally.

The easiest way (if you're not on windows) is with gvm

http://gvmtool.net